# Flutter dynamically set font size based on screen width using mediaquery

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() { runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation Basics',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
              bodyText1: TextStyle(
            fontSize: getFontSize(context), // any hardcoded value like `10` works
          ))),
      home: const Homepage(),
    );
    // const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
  }
}

double getFontSize(BuildContext context) {
  var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double fontSize;
  if (screenWidth <= 992) {
    fontSize = 40;
  } else {
    fontSize = 32;
  }
  return fontSize;
}
```

Error - `No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.`
`No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you have not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.`

Comment: Generally, that's a bad idea.  You don't change the font size, you should change the layout (side by side vs top to bottom, or two columns vs three columns).  That's best done with LayoutBuilder, not MediaQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added MediaQuery Widget in the top of widgt tree try this

```
return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData(
        textScaleFactor: 1.0, // change according to your requirement
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Navigation Basics',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
            textTheme: TextTheme(
                bodyText1: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: getFontSize(context), // any hardcoded value like `10` works
                ))),
        home: const Homepage(),
      ),
    )
```